# Access files on filesystem in Tampermonkey on Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, tampermonkey

I want to load a userscript from the local filesystem in Tampermonkey using `@require` on versions of Firefox that use the new extension format. On Chrome, it's very easy since all that is needed to go to `chrome://extensions` and turn on the switch for `Allow access to file URLs` for Tampermonkey. How do I do this on Firefox?

Comment: https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tampermonkey/issues/347

Comment: I guess you'll have to set up a local web server, there are simple-to-use utilities for that.